# Mailto line break not working on yahoo

Tags: email, html-email, mailto, yahoo-mail

I am having an issue with line break not working on yahoo. I have used this code `%0D%0A` and it work well on Gmail, Outlook, etc. but not on Yahoo. But when using `<br>` it will work on yahoo but not on outlook. Does anybody here can help that would work on all email?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: add them both :)

Comment: `<br><br/>` work just fine in Outlook. What are you doing to stop it from working? Post your code so we can help.